# Web server and ZeroMQ patterns

Tags: zeromq

I am running an Apache server that receives HTTP requests and connects to a daemon script over ZeroMQ. The script implements the Multithreaded Server pattern (http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#header-73), it successfully receives the request and dispatches it to one of its worker threads, performs the action, responds back to the server, and the server responds back to the client. Everything is done synchronously as the client needs to receive a success or failure response to its request.

As the number of users is growing into a few thousands, I am looking into potentially improving this. The first thing I looked at is the different patterns of ZeroMQ, and whether what I am using is optimal for my scenario. I've read the guide but I find it challenging understanding all the details and differences across patterns. I was looking for example at the Load Balancing Message Broker pattern (http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#header-73). It seems quite a bit more complicated to implement than what I am currently using, and if I understand things correctly, its advantages are:

1. Actual load balancing vs the round-robin task distribution that I currently have
2. Asynchronous requests/replies

Is that everything? Am I missing something? Given the description of my problem, and the synchronous requirement of it, what would you say is the best pattern to use? Lastly, how would the answer change, if I want to make my setup distributed (i.e. having the Apache server load balance the requests across different machines). I was thinking of doing that by simply creating yet another layer, based on the Multithreaded Server pattern, and have that layer bridge the communication between the web server and my workers.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts about the subject...

### Keep it simple

I would try to keep things simple and "plain" ZeroMQ as long as possible. To increase performance, I would simply to change your backend script to send request out from dealer socket and move the request handling code to own program. Then you could just run multiple worker servers in different machines to get more requests handled.

I assume this was the approach you took:

> I was thinking of doing that by simply creating yet another layer, based on the Multithreaded Server pattern, and have that layer bridge the communication between the web server and my workers.

Only problem here is that there is no request retry in the backend. If worker fails to handle given task it is forever lost. However one could write worker servers so that they handle all the request they got before shutting down. With this kind of setup it is possible to update backend workers without clients to notice any shortages. This will not save requests that get lost if the server crashes.

I have the feeling that in common scenarios this kind of approach would be more than enough.

### Mongrel2

Mongrel2 seems to handle quite many things you have already implemented. It might be worth while to check it out. It probably does not completely solve your problems, but it provides tested infrastructure to distribute the workload. This could be used to deliver the request to be handled to multithreaded servers running on different machines.

### Broker

One solution to increase the robustness of the setup is a broker. In this scenario brokers main role would be to provide robustness by implementing queue for the requests. I understood that all the requests the worker handle are basically the same type. If requests would have different types then broker could also do lookups to find correct server for the requests.

Using the queue provides a way to ensure that every request is being handled by some broker even if worker servers crashed. This does not come without price. The broker is by itself a single point of failure. If it crashes or is restarted all messages could be lost.

These problems can be avoided, but it requires quite much work: the requests could be persisted to the disk, servers could be clustered. Need has to be weighted against the payoffs. Does one want to use time to write a message broker or the actual system?

If message broker seems a good idea the time which is required to implement one can be reduced by using already implemented product (like RabbitMQ). Negative side effect is that there could be a lot of unwanted features and adding new things is not so straight forward as to self made broker.

Writing own broker could covert toward inventing the wheel again. Many brokers provide similar things: security, logging, management interface and so on. It seems likely that these are eventually needed in home made solution also. But if not then single home made broker which does single thing and does it well can be good choice.

Even if broker product is chosen I think it is a good idea to hide the broker behind ZeroMQ proxy, a dedicated code that sends/receives messages from the broker. Then no other part of the system has to know anything about the broker and it can be easily replaced.

Using broker is somewhat developer time heavy. You either need time to implement the broker or time to get use to some product. I would avoid this route until it is clearly needed.

Some links

- [Comparison between broker and brokerless](http://zeromq.org/whitepapers:brokerless)
- [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)
- [Mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org)